# iPhone Reachable classes

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, reachability

I have added the two files Reachability.h/m.
The problem I am having is in the ReachabilityCallback method

```
NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");
```

The error message is: Cast of C pointer type 'void *' to Objective-C pointer type 'NSObject * requires a bridged cast

```
NSAutoreleasePool* myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

Error: 'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Error: Implicit conversion of an Object-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC

There is a bunch of ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'/'autorelease'.

Is there a version of the code that will work for ARC?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add `-fno-objc-arc` to compile flags for the source file. Or use a better implementation available on github.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
NSCAssert([(__bridge NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try tonymillion's [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability#readme) classes, they're ARC and GCD compatible.