# Reachability class ARC error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, reachability

Hi. I imported reachability.h file and reachability.m file in order to check the internet connection in my application but I'm getting an ARC error.

I have to tried to convert application into ARC but it's still showing the same error as follows:

```
compile Reachability.m and compile Reachability m files

implicit conversion of objective c pointer type 'Reachability *' to Cpointer type void * requires a bridged  cast

   ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'
   ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
   ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

  'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
  'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
   Cast of C pointer type 'void*' to Objective - C pointer type 'Rachability*' requires a bridged cast 
  release is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

  ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please I need help.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620271/reachability-h-reachability-m-gives-an-apple-mach-o-linker-error-while-adding

Comment: Remove the lines of code which belongs to the memory release.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11945045/1142743

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: but getting warning like this warning: no rule to process file how to resolve this one @iDev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add your classes to stop arc mode

[image]

Comment: but getting warning  like this warning: no rule to process file how to resolve this one @iDev

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want to use the class as-is you can always [enable ARC for just a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523816/how-to-enable-arc-for-a-single-file), not the complete project.

Pretty handy for including third-party sources that either require or don't ARC.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an older version of the code. Refer to the Apple sample code for [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which is updated to use ARC.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read Apple documentation about the transition to ARC: [Transition to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

As you will learn ARC automatically dealloc objects in memory based on how many strong pointer are currently pointing to a specific object. When no strong pointers (zero) to an objects are left ARC will dealloc that object immediately. Therefore you won't use autorelease anymore as all the objects are autoreleased with ARC.

You can call dealloc (although I wouldn't do it except if strictly necessary) to run some come prior the object to be dealloc'd by ARC. It's very important however that in the dealloc method you don't call the super class method (which I assume is the causes of the errors associated to dealloc) as this will be completely handled by ARC. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to any files for which you'd like to enable **ARC**, as described    in the **ARC** documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Reachability file you are using is *older version*. You can download latest version of [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) file compatible with iOS 6.0 and later.

For older version of Reachability files you can add some flags to enable ARC

1. Open *Targets* of your project
2. Select *Build Phases*
3. Open *Compile Sources* tab
4. Double click next to *Reachability* file
5. Add `-fno-objc-arc` flag

[image: Screenshot for above steps]